# How can I put a downloadable file into the HttpServletResponse?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, httpresponse, outputstream

I have the following problem: I have an **HttpServlet** that create a file and return it to the user that have to receive it as a download

```
byte[] byteArray = allegato.getFile();

InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArray);
Base64InputStream base64InputStream = new Base64InputStream(is);

int chunk = 1024;
byte[] buffer = new byte[chunk];
int bytesRead = -1;

OutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

while ((bytesRead = base64InputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
    out.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
}
```

As you can see I have a **byteArray** object that is an array of bytes (**byte[] byteArray**) and I convert it into a file in this way:

1. First I convert it into an **InputStream** object.
2. Then I convert the **InputStream** object into a **Base64InputStream**.
3. Finally I write this **Base64InputStream** on a **ByteArrayOutputStream** object (the **OutputStream out** object).

I think that up to here it should be ok (is it ok or am I missing something in the file creation?)

Now my servlet have to return this file as a dowload (so the user have to receive the download into the browser).

So what have I to do to obtain this behavior? I think that I have to put this **OutputStream** object into the Servlet response, something like:

```
ServletOutputStream stream = res.getOutputStream();
```

But I have no idea about how exactly do it? Have I also to set a specific MIME type for the file?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's pretty easy to do.

```
byte[] byteArray = //your byte array

response.setContentType("YOUR CONTENT TYPE HERE");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "filename=\"THE FILE NAME\"");
response.setContentLength(byteArray.length);
OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();

try {
   os.write(byteArray , 0, byteArray.length);
} catch (Exception excp) {
   //handle error
} finally {
    os.close();
}
```

EDIT:
I've noticed that you are first decoding your data from base64, the you should do the following:

```
OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();
byte[] buffer = new byte[chunk];
int bytesRead = -1;

while ((bytesRead = base64InputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
    os.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
}
```

You do not need the intermediate `ByteArrayOutputStream`

Comment: mmm so are you telling me that I have not to put the ByteArrayOutputStream into the HttpResponse OutputStream  but I have to put here my byte array? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Exactly. You can write to the response output stream directly.

Comment: I've updated my ansewr, because I notice that you do base64 decoding. About the content type - the MIME content type of the response like "application/json", "text/plain" etc, whatever the content type of your response is. I do not know what you are sending so I cannot give you the concrete type. Just google about MIME type

Comment: It is a .sap file and I am not finding the correct MIME type for this kind of file. Do you know something about it? Or exist a generic MIME type?

Comment: You can use `application/octet-stream`. The RFC says: The "octet-stream" subtype is used to indicate that a body contains arbitrary binary data" and "The recommended action for an implementation that receives an "application/octet-stream" entity is to simply offer to put the data in a file

Answer (score 0):

With `org.apache.commons.compress.utils.IOUtils` you can just "copy" from one file or stream (e.g. your `base64InputStream`) to the output stream:

```
    response.setContentType([your file mime type]);
    IOUtils.copy(base64InputStream, response.getOutputStream());
    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
```

You'll find that class here https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-compress

A similar class (also named IOUtils) is also in Apache Commons IO (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io).